# How to do multiple ui on one main window

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

I'm very novice of python. I want to create app with multiple ui on one main window.

e.g at MainWindow

first ui : display company info and a button (next). when user click "Next" button, go to second ui.

second ui : display some listing and two buttons (next and back). When user click "Next", go to third ui. when user click "Back" button, go back to first ui (about company info).

third ui : display some info and two buttons (next and back), when user click "Next", go to fourth ui. When user click "Back" button, go back to second ui (listing ui).

I tried as follow. But I can't. How should I do?

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

class OtherWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        layout = QHBoxLayout()
        lineEdit = QLineEdit()
        lineEdit.setText("Just to fill up the dialog")
        layout.addWidget(lineEdit)

        button = QPushButton()
        layout.addWidget(button)

        self.widget = QWidget()
        self.widget.setLayout(layout)

        self.setCentralWidget(self.widget)
        self.setWindowTitle("Win2")
        self.connect(button, SIGNAL('clicked()'), self.newWindow)


    def newWindow(self):
        self.myOtherWindow = MainWindow()
        self.myOtherWindow.show()



class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        layout = QHBoxLayout()
        button = QPushButton()
        layout.addWidget(button)

        self.widget = QWidget()
        self.widget.setLayout(layout)

        self.setCentralWidget(self.widget)
        self.setWindowTitle("Win1")

        self.connect(button, SIGNAL('clicked()'), self.newWindow)


    def newWindow(self):
        self.myOtherWindow = OtherWindow()
        self.myOtherWindow.show()

if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainWindow = MainWindow()
    mainWindow.setGeometry(100, 100, 200, 200)
    mainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Can't you use a QWizard dialog ?

Comment: Yes I saw it. but I'm very novice for python. So I can't catch it clearly. but I've an idea to try it on my next proj.

Answer (score 1):

I got it. Base on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11166712/what-is-best-way-to-remove-items-from-layout-in-pyqt). And I modified as follow.

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui,QtCore
class LayoutTest(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(LayoutTest, self).__init__()
        self.first_box  = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.second_box = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.third_box  = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.fourth_box = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()

        self.zvbox = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()

        vbox = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        vbox.addLayout(self.first_box)
        vbox.addLayout(self.second_box)
        vbox.addLayout(self.third_box)
        vbox.addLayout(self.fourth_box)
        self.setLayout(vbox)

        self.first_view()

        self.setGeometry(300, 200, 400, 300)

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        if event.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_Escape:
            self.close()

    def first_view(self):

        self.next1 = QtGui.QPushButton("NEXT 2")

        self.first_box.addWidget(self.next1)

        self.connect(self.next1, QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.first_second_view)

    def first_second_view(self):
        self.remove_first_view()
        self.second_view()

    def second_view(self):


        self.next3 = QtGui.QPushButton("NEXT 3")
        self.back1 = QtGui.QPushButton("BACK 1")

        self.second_box.addWidget(self.next3)
        self.second_box.addWidget(self.back1)

        self.connect(self.next3, QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.second_third_view)
        self.connect(self.back1, QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.second_first_view)

    def second_first_view(self):
        self.remove_second_view()
        self.first_view()



    def second_third_view(self):
        self.remove_second_view()
        self.third_view()




    def third_view(self):

        self.next4 = QtGui.QPushButton("NEXT 4")
        self.back2 = QtGui.QPushButton("BACK 2")

        self.third_box.addWidget(self.next4)
        self.third_box.addWidget(self.back2)

        self.connect(self.next4, QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.third_fourth_view)
        self.connect(self.back2, QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.third_second_view)

    def third_second_view(self):
        self.remove_third_view()
        self.second_view()


    def third_fourth_view(self):
        self.remove_third_view()
        self.back3 = QtGui.QPushButton("BACK 3")

        self.fourth_box.addWidget(self.back3)

        self.connect(self.back3, QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.fourth_third_view)

    def fourth_third_view(self):
        self.remove_fourth_view()
        self.third_view()

    def remove_first_view(self):
        for cnt in reversed(range(self.first_box.count())):
            # takeAt does both the jobs of itemAt and removeWidget
            # namely it removes an item and returns it
            widget = self.first_box.takeAt(cnt).widget()

            if widget is not None: 
                # widget will be None if the item is a layout
                widget.deleteLater()

    def remove_second_view(self):
        for cnt in reversed(range(self.second_box.count())):
            # takeAt does both the jobs of itemAt and removeWidget
            # namely it removes an item and returns it
            widget = self.second_box.takeAt(cnt).widget()

            if widget is not None: 
                # widget will be None if the item is a layout
                widget.deleteLater()

    def remove_third_view(self):
        for cnt in reversed(range(self.third_box.count())):
            # takeAt does both the jobs of itemAt and removeWidget
            # namely it removes an item and returns it
            widget = self.third_box.takeAt(cnt).widget()

            if widget is not None: 
                # widget will be None if the item is a layout
                widget.deleteLater()

    def remove_fourth_view(self):
        for cnt in reversed(range(self.fourth_box.count())):
            # takeAt does both the jobs of itemAt and removeWidget
            # namely it removes an item and returns it
            widget = self.fourth_box.takeAt(cnt).widget()

            if widget is not None: 
                # widget will be None if the item is a layout
                widget.deleteLater()


    def checkItems(self):
        QtGui.QMessageBox.information(self, 'Count',"You have %s Items in Layout" % self.dvbox.count(), QtGui.QMessageBox.Ok)

def run():

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = LayoutTest()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    run()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an example using the `QWizard` and `QWizardPage` classes:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 *-

import sys
import os

from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

class MyWizard(QtGui.QWizard):
  def __init__(self, parent = None):
    QtGui.QWizard.__init__(self, parent)
    self.result = 0
    self.company_name = ""
    self.company_listing = ""
    self.info1 = ""
    self.info2 = ""
    self.info3 = ""

    self.setWindowTitle("My wizard")
    self.addPage(company_info(self))
    self.addPage(company_listing(self))
    self.addPage(company_other_infos(self))

    self.finished.connect(self.end)
    pass

  def end(self, result):
    self.result = result
    if self.result:
      self.company_name = str(self.field("company_name").toString())
      self.company_listing = str(self.field("company_listing").toString())
      self.info1 = str(self.field("info1").toString())
      self.info2 = str(self.field("info2").toString())
      self.info3 = str(self.field("info3").toString())
    print self.company_name
    print self.company_listing
    print self.info1
    print self.info2
    print self.info3

class company_info(QtGui.QWizardPage):
  def __init__(self, parent):
    QtGui.QWizardPage.__init__(self, parent)
    self.setTitle("Step 1/3")
    self.setSubTitle("Company Name")
    # Name
    self.lineEdit = QtGui.QLineEdit("The world company")
    # Fields
    self.registerField("company_name", self.lineEdit)
    # Page layout
    layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
    layout.addWidget(self.lineEdit)
    layout.addStretch(1)
    self.setLayout(layout)

  def isComplete(self):
    if self.lineEdit.text() == "The world company":
      self.completeChanged.emit()
      return True
    return False

class company_listing(QtGui.QWizardPage):
  def __init__(self, parent):
    QtGui.QWizardPage.__init__(self, parent)
    self.setTitle("Step 2/3")
    self.setSubTitle("Some listing")
    ipsum = """Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec a diam lectus. Sed sit amet ipsum mauris.
Maecenas congue ligula ac quam viverra nec consectetur ante hendrerit. Donec et mollis dolor.
#Praesent et diam eget libero egestas mattis sit amet vitae augue.
Nam tincidunt congue enim, ut porta lorem lacinia consectetur. Donec ut libero sed arcu vehicula ultricies a non tortor.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean ut gravida lorem.
Ut turpis felis, pulvinar a semper sed, adipiscing id dolor. Pellentesque auctor nisi id magna consequat sagittis.
Curabitur dapibus enim sit amet elit pharetra tincidunt feugiat nisl imperdiet.
Ut convallis libero in urna ultrices accumsan. Donec sed odio eros.
Donec viverra mi quis quam pulvinar at malesuada arcu rhoncus.
Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.
In rutrum accumsan ultricies. Mauris vitae nisi at sem facilisis semper ac in est."""
    # Some listing in a table widget
    textEdit = QtGui.QTextEdit()
    textEdit.setPlainText(ipsum)
    # Fields
    self.registerField("company_listing", textEdit, "plainText")
    # Page layout
    layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
    layout.addWidget(textEdit)
    layout.addStretch(1)
    self.setLayout(layout)
    pass

  def initializePage(self):
    pass

  def cleanupPage(self):
    pass

class company_other_infos(QtGui.QWizardPage):
  def __init__(self, parent):
    QtGui.QWizardPage.__init__(self, parent)
    self.setTitle("Step 3/3")
    self.setSubTitle("Other infos")
    # Other infos
    lineEdit_info1 = QtGui.QLineEdit("info1")
    lineEdit_info2 = QtGui.QLineEdit("info2")
    lineEdit_info3 = QtGui.QLineEdit("info3")
    # Fields
    self.registerField("info1", lineEdit_info1)
    self.registerField("info2", lineEdit_info2)
    self.registerField("info3", lineEdit_info3)
    # Page layout
    layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
    layout.addWidget(lineEdit_info1)
    layout.addWidget(lineEdit_info2)
    layout.addWidget(lineEdit_info3)
    layout.addStretch(1)
    self.setLayout(layout)

  def initializePage(self):
    pass

  def cleanupPage(self):
    pass

myWizard = MyWizard()
myWizard.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: OK, @Frodon. I've some questions. If I want to validate on a page, how can I do? e.g The company name must be "The world company". But if it is not, I don't want to go to next page ""company_listing" page. And if I want to show the validation error at "company_info" page, how should I do?

Comment: @ThuRa This is done in the isComplete method: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwizardpage.html#isComplete. Have a look at the doc page of QWizardPage, everything is explained. For instance if you want a field to be mandatory, add an '*' to its name: self.registerField("company_name*", lineEdit)

Comment: Where do I put the isComplete()? after "self.registerField("company_name", lineEdit)"?

Comment: This is another method, like initializePage(self) or cleanupPage(self), that you have to rewrite. See my edit.